# System.Data assembly binding failure after visual studio 2012 installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

After having installed visual studio 2012 on clear windows 7 machine i've issues running such applications as powershell,eventviewer and sql server setup.

In FusionLogViewer there are logs for failed binding for assembly System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
 for powershell  with error code hr = 0x80131018.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems to be that System.Data.dll, System.Web.dll, webengine.dll and aspnet_wp.exe 
in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 were substituted with invalid coff files during Visual Studio 2012 installation. I've succeeded in managing this problem only by replacing files by analogs from valid .net installation. Reinstalling .net framework and switching on/off windows components for .net 3.5 didn't have any effect.